# Burning cards in Hold 'em

Tags: texas-hold-em

I forgot to burn any cards playing Texas Hold 'em. This was pointed out by someone else after the hand was finished. I thought it should have been a miss deal, but the guy who won the hand insisted I pay him the all in of $25. What should we have really done and is there a rule on this?

Comment: If you said call you pay.  It is not a miss deal after the action the action is over.

Comment: There is never a misdeal after the hand is finished without highly unusual circumstances, like cheating and weapons drawn.

Answer (score 3):

This isn't explicitly a misdeal as per the TDA rules, to quote:

> A: Misdeals include but are not necessarily limited to: 1) 2 or more boxed cards on the initial deal; 2)
>   first card dealt to the wrong seat; 3) cards dealt to a seat not entitled to a hand; 4) a seat entitled to a
>   hand is dealt out; 5) In stud, if any of the first 2 down cards are exposed by dealer error; 6) In flop
>   games, if either of the first 2 cards dealt off the deck or any other 2 downcards are exposed by dealer
>   error. House standards apply for draw games (ex: lowball).

If you've gone as far as to play to a winner, it is far less disruptive to let the hand stand than to declare it a misdeal. Pay the man his money and move on to the next hand, dealing properly.